# Inherit Cell Colour Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vlookup formula that is pulling results from table A and the cell that contains the results are coloured differently. I would like the colour of the cell to be inherited from table A to table B.

What would be the VBA formula to achieve this please?

Many thanks!

Comment: what was wrong about [copying the format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/copy-formats-from-one-cell-or-range-to-another-HP005199434.aspx) manually? assuming the original range uses conditional formatting based on its own value..

Comment: You can't do this using a formula.

Comment: Well it's just for ease of use and quick alterations. Really, table A is the main source of data that is transferred to more than one table. You're right to assume that conditional formatting is used for the values in table A.

Comment: Aprillion is right. @user1164109 were you able to apply it?

Comment: No VBA required. Apply the same conditional formatting in table B as well. When the value changes in table B, the colors will also changes.